# Bitcoin Java RPC client - cannot create raw transaction

Tags: java, java-8, bitcoin

I'm using the java implementation of Bitcoin RPC client.
When I'm calling the `createRawTransaction` with int type the raw transaction created as expected:

```
BitcoindRpcClient.TxOutput txOut1 = new BitcoindRpcClient.BasicTxOutput(issuerAddress,
                    new BigDecimal(1));
```

When I'm trying to use double value instead of int:

```
BitcoindRpcClient.TxOutput txOut1 = new BitcoindRpcClient.BasicTxOutput(issuerAddress,
                    new BigDecimal(1.2));
```

I'm receiving this error: `invalid amount`.

When I'm trying it by using `bitcoin-cli`, it works as expected.

**NOTE**: I;m working on local testnet blockchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal(1.2));
System.out.println(BigDecimal.valueOf(1.2));
```

Is:

```
1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
1.2
```

So the short answer is to use the preferred way to convert a double: `BigDecimal.valueOf(1.2)`

The long answer is that floatting numbers are complicated and `double` is an approximation for 1.2